# [[EmailBlurb]] text appearing in docusign Welcome page

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign showing the Email Blurb and it's not supposed to

[image: image description]

I'm not sure why the emailbody set for the [[EmailBlurb]] appearing in the DocuSignWelcome page. Is there are way to remove it from the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you would be having `DocuSign_WelcomeDialogHideEmailContent` value as `false` in your branding's signing resource file. You need to change it to

```
<data name="DocuSign_WelcomeDialogHideEmailContent">true</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

true need to be mentioned in the signingresource file to make the EmailBlurb not appear on the welcome sceen. Thank you once again Anil